# java - get selected value of defaultlistmodule

Tags: java, swing

OK so I'm trying to get the value of the selected of JList and I tried reading [the API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html)... I am using a DefaultListModule to store whats in my JList...

```
public DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
```

and a JList

```
public JList list;
```

and here is how I add:

```
model.addElement("Testing for this example");
```

and here is where I get NullPointerException:

```
Object dropped = model.getElementAt(list.getSelectedIndex());
```

and here is how I set-up my JLIST

```
    list = new JList(model);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.addMouseListener(this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a NullPointerException either model or list is null. Since you postet the initialization of the model I'd guess that you didn't initialize the list itself.

```
public JList list = new JList(model);
```

Also make sure that getSelectedIndex doesn't return -1.

Comment: Oh, I know why! It's because I am removing it from the list THEN I get the name so I get NULL! :D

Comment: If you did that it's impossible that you get an NPE on this line: model.getElementAt(list.getSelectedIndex());. getElementAt only throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and getSelectedIndex never throws. Please post the stacktrace of the exception. Oh. Nevermind then.

Comment: So the problem was because you "removed it from the list". Where in the posted code do you display that line of code. There is no possible way we could have solved this problem based on the information provided in this question.